# Can I change a free app to subscription based app?

Tags: iphone, app-store

Is it legally and programmatically possible to upload a free app to the AppStore, and after a while to change it to subscription model, so the main feature will be locked for non-subscribers?

tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an app that is free and then later on add an in-app purchase (e.g) such as a subscription. Note, that an in-app purchase cannot be free so you cannot start with a free in-app purchase and then just increase the price.

Note that the original downloaders of the app who haven't upgraded will still get the main feature for free unless you code the app in advance (from the start) to change behaviour when you add the in-app subscription.

Comment: Also note that changing how the app works with an update isn't something users love: better you tell them in advance "free for now" than let discover it the new price policy with an update...

Comment: yes, prepare for an onslaught of negative reviews when you start charging. it's bad enough when you introduce ads - let alone forcing an in-app purchase.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, it is possible to submit a free up and then move to a subscription model but it is highly recommended to code the application in advance for such, plus make sure your users know what is comming ahead. Otherwise they could get really nasty...

Here is a good tutorial for implementing in app purchase: http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/